# BACK-PORTING can use PDFDocument (API 19) in jellybean API 16?

Tags: android, pdf, android-support-library

I'm compiling using `Android 4.4.2 (API19)` but running on `Android 4.1.1 API 16`.
Is there an Android support library, or something, so I can use `PdfDocument.java` (API 19) in `Jellybean API 16`?

Code:

```
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument.Page;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument.PageInfo;

        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
```

Error log:

```
07-22 14:58:41.869: E/dalvikvm(4165): Could not find class
'android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument', referenced from method com.example.html2pdf.Html2pdfActivity.button1onClick

07-22 14:59:33.965: E/AndroidRuntime(4165): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument
```

**Can I package up the required system library and put it in my App? (or somehow bypass/relocate the system call)?**

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, Google has not published a backport of `PdfDocument` or pretty much anything related to the Android 4.4+ printing APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Still, google has not backported the `PdfDocument` API (API 19). But you can use pdfium library from [AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/pdfium/) or the fork from [PdfiumAndroid](https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid) for PDF document.